# Adding Coordinates to shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, error-000800

I want to add latitude and longitude column and their values in decimal degrees to my shapefile (fishnet). How to use ArcPy for that?

I have added lat and long using `arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management` but the unit I need is degree decimal and I got it in meters. My code is as below:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("fish_lyr","CENTROID")
```

When specifying degree decimal:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("fish_lyr","CENTROID","DEGREEDECIMALS")
```

it gives the following error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of FEET_US | METERS | KILOMETERS | MILES_US | NAUTICAL_MILES | YARDS.
Failed to execute (AddGeometryAttributes).
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the da.UpdateCursor with the SHAPE@ token:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\Test\Buildings.shp'
latfield = 'lat'
longfield = 'long'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['SHAPE@',latfield,longfield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        a = arcpy.PointGeometry(row[0].centroid, arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference)
        b = a.projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)).centroid
        row[1], row[2] = b.Y, b.X
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the case where the OP or a future reader can use geopandas instead of arcpy, you would do the following:

```
shp = 'C:/users/gis/data/fish.shp'
gdf = geopandas.read_file(shp)
(
    gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'}
        .assign(lon=lambda df: df['geometry'].centroid.x)
        .assign(lat=lambda df: df['geometry'].centroid.y)
        .to_crs(gdf.crs) 
        .to_file(shp)
)
```

Comment: @BERA I forgot to add the coordinate conversion. But I'm well aware that the OP wanted `arcpy`. If you read initial the premise of my answer, you'll see that I clearly acknowledged that. However, this could be a case of an X-Y problem for a different reader in the future, which case geopandas could make their life much easier.

Comment: In epsg:4326 the first axis (x) is lat, though

Comment: @mmtoken, With geopandas/shapely, that order doesn't matter. Latitude, _then longitude_ may be how we say these values, but latitude is still the y-direction. When I do this with a shape file near Portland, OR, USA, I get longitude values around -122.75 and latitude values around 45.57, which is what I expect.